# Find the value of $\sum ^{2020}_{n=1} n^{2019} \pmod{2019}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$\displaystyle \sum ^{2020}_{n=1} n^{2019} \pmod{2019}$
Well on internet there are solution which uses the fact that for odd $n$,
$\displaystyle a^{n} +b^{n}$
is divisible by $a+b$ to solve this problem however I need a solution. Using Fermat's little theorem here is what I have done so far.

$2019=673 \times 3$

$\displaystyle \sum ^{2020}_{n=1} n^{2019} \equiv \displaystyle \sum ^{2020}_{n=1} n^{3} \pmod{ 673}$

$\displaystyle \sum ^{2020}_{n=1} n^{3} \pmod{ 673}=1$

In $\frac{ka+c}{a} =k$ ,remainder=$c$ and in $\frac{3( ka+c)}{3a} =k$, remainder=$3c$

Now we have $\displaystyle 3\sum ^{2020}_{n=1} n^{3} \equiv 3 \pmod{2019}$

Now I am not able to do further please help.

Comment: Sorry for using "equal to" instead of "congruence" sign

Comment: I have edited your problem. You can use \equiv for $\equiv$.

Comment: @Doug M
$\displaystyle \left( n^{3}\right)^{673} \equiv n^{3} \ ( mod\ 673)$
Will be right as according to fermat's little theorem modulus has to be prime number and 2019 is not prime.

Comment: you should comment below his answer, not here I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

First on the work above:
$n^{2019}\equiv n^3\pmod{2019}$ (not $\pmod{ 673}$)

With these competition type problems were you are summing to an arbitrarily large number, try a few examples with small numbers and see if you can spot a pattern.  If you can, can you justify it?

Note that for $a\ne 2019$
$(2019-a)^3 = 2019^3 + 3\cdot 2019^2a + 3\cdot 2019a^2 - a^3\\
(2019-a)^3 \equiv -a^3\pmod {2019}$

We can pair off from both ends...

$\sum_\limits {n=1}^{2018} n^{3}\pmod{2019} = \sum_\limits {n=1}^{1009} 2019$

And the last two are simple.

$1009\cdot 2019 + 1$